# React Props are only available in componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

I have a child react component that receives props but they are only available in componentWillReceiveProps. They are null in componentDidMount. I don't want to use that event since it is deprecated.  Do I have any other options?

Comment: Check this [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Answer (score -1):

Props are null or undefined? Props passed to a child component from a parent component are available in componentDidMount.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
}
```